# MonoGame templates in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2015, monogame

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 and now want to start a new MonoGame project (C#, Windows DX).
I got MonoGame installed, as well as XNA.

The problem is that the templates are not showing up in the *New Project* dialogue.

[image]

On Visual Studio 2013, they showed up here, they are also nowhere to be found aynwhere else in the Project tree.

So I searched for the templates, they exist in the location where they should be:

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\MonoGame`

[image]

I tried running the `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` from the Visual Studio admin console, as well as `devenv.exe /setup`, for good measure.
After doing both several times, mixed with a few Visual Studio 2015 and Windows restarts, the project templates are still not showing up.

I also tried to clear the cache by deleting `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio` and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`, to no avail.

The MonoGame installer was customized to work with Visual Studio 2015, so I assume it should work somehow.

So, can anyone help me getting those project templates set up?

Comment: That is the installer I used.

Comment: How can i open visual studio admin console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working:

Apparently, the MonoGame installer puts the Templates in the wrong folder for Visual Studio 2015.

The correct folder for VS2015 is

C:\Users\user\Documents\**Visual Studio 14**\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

The MonoGame installer installs to C:\Users\user\Documents\**Visual Studio 2015**\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

So, when the folder MonoGame inside that folder gets moved to the first one, and the `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` command gets executed, the templates show up.

Comment: Thank you @nilllzz, you saved me a ton of time!

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 14 folder

Answer (score 2):

In case you work as standard user and run MonoGame setup as admin, MonoGane templates was installed only in Administrator account.

So I just make copy into my user `\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#`.

**MonoGame Setup installation:**

```
C:\Users\**Admin**\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#
```

**Correct folder is under my user account:**

```
C:\Users\**user**\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#
```

Then as answered above just run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` from Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.