# MonoGame templates won't show in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, monogame

I recently tried to move from Unity2D to MonoGame to learn C# better. After I installed MonoGame, opened Visual Studio, and started a new project, I didn't see any of the MonoGame project templates. The MonoGame files are in their place.

**I can run any kind of MonoGame project, but I can't create a new one.**

I tried to:

- Reinstall VS and MonoGame
- Format my PC
- Download, but install myself.

Note: I seen some more questions about this, they were solved, so I tried every single solution they had and nothing worked. This is not a duplicate, this problem is different.

Comment: [Here is a similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893755/monogame-templates-in-visual-studio-2015) which says that Monogame installs the templates into the wrong folder. Check [this](http://community.monogame.net/t/vs2015-no-templates/2827) out too. (Although I've just tried installing the official MonoGame v3.4 from 04/2015 and it worked with VS2015 community).

Comment: @Groo i remember i saw it a few day ago when i faced the problem. i tried to do it, but i cant find 'visual studio 2014' at 'c:/users/user'.

Comment: Do you have any visual studio folders inside c:\users\jonathan\documents (or whatever your username is)? You also need to run the ´devenv´ command mentioned in that other thread to register these templates once in place. Are you sure you have the latest monogame 3.4 installer? I had this issue with an older monogame version, but it seems to be fixed in this build. I am running the VS2015 community edition.

Answer (score 1):

I copied Monogame folder from **"$DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\" (with $DOCUMENTS referring to your user documents folder)** to my actual VS2015 Project Templates(during installation which i selected) folder.And it's worked fine for me.
Screenshots for further help:
[image]

```
                                          TO
```

[image]